Can adb be leveraged to send commands to a running Linux application
I have a c++ application running on a linux device that supports adb and is connected to my laptop. The application does have a local server running.
void TCPServer::start()
         {
             try
             {
                 server_socket_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                 if (server_socket_ < 0)
                 {
                     LOG("Failed to create socket\n");
                     return;
                 }
     
                 int opt = 1;
                 if (setsockopt(server_socket_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0) {
                     close(server_socket_);
                     return;
                 }
                 struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
                 server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
                 server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
                 server_addr.sin_port = htons(port_);
     
                 if (bind(server_socket_, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
                 {
                     LOG("Failed to bind server socket");
                     close(server_socket_);
                     return;
                 }
     
                 if (listen(server_socket_, 1) < 0)
                 {
                     LOG("Failed to listen on server socket")    ;
                     close(server_socket_);
                     return;
                 }
     
                 struct pollfd fds[1];
                 fds[0].fd = server_socket_;
                 fds[0].events = POLLIN;
                 static const int READY_TIMEOUT = 3000;
                 while (!isStopRequested())
                 { 
                     int ready = poll(fds, 1, READY_TIMEOUT);
                     if (ready < 0)
                     {
                         LOG("polling error");
                         break;
                     }
                     else if (ready == 0)
                     {
                         LOG("timed out");
                         break;
                     }
                     if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN)
{
                         // New connection
                         int client_socket = accept(server_socket_, NULL, NULL);
                         if (client_socket < 0)
                         {
                             LOG("Failed to accept connection");
                             close(server_socket_);
                             return;
                         }
                         // perform some operation
                     }
                 }
             }
             catch (std::exception ecep)
             {
                 LOG("exception", excep.what());
             }
         }

Is it possible to send custom commands to this application through adb itself for the application to perform some operations if the command is correct?
To provide more context, I want to send a valid json either as a string or a file: if this is not feasible what other mechanism can I use to communicate with the linux application through adb?
I can add new functionality to the linux application if that matters here. Please note I did consider pushing a json file on device and then reading on launch, but the problem is that I need to send multiple commands and I can not batch all of these commands in one file.

You can use adb to set-up a port forwarding using adb forward (if the adb implementation on the device implements it).

@Robert sorry I do not understand after setting up port forwarding, how can I use adb to send commands, can you give an example or is the suggestion to have an application on the device that tries to connect to device and than send commands through sockets

You have a server on the Android device. adb does not make use of network services, it can only call special commands on the shell. It is not designed to integrate commands of third party services unless you call them vai adb shell <command. Thus if you want to commuicate via TCP you have to build your own client for the PC side. Just think of adb as an ssh-like connection (with less security and no login).

Thanks @Robert, so if I understand correctly we would have to either do adb forwarding and have an application running on the computer to send commands over socket or have another application running on device and then we do adb shell %new_apllication% { command} right. This is not an android device. Although not that familiar with adb I did try to look into whether I could use adb am broadcast {command} but was did not find anything that could be written on the native application to receive commands that way.

In the second case the on-device application doesn't have to run all the time, you just start it using the adb shell command. How this command communicates with the server is up to you (e.g. unix named pipe). If it is not an Android device my guess is that only adb sub-commands like shell forward reverse will work, not am as these are simply shortcuts to adb shell somecommand where somecommand is then an executable command on the Android device.
